# Test Script success by matching output lines

Tags: shell

I have a script that checking a folder and output three lines :

`1st line : Changes to the subfolders
2nd line : Changes to the number of files
3rd line : Changes of file size in the folder`

This is an example of output :

`1 sub-folders added
Number of files didn't change
Files size didn't change`

I want to use a command to check the output line by line and test the script.

Something like

`line 1 == "1 sub-folders added" && line 2 == "Number of files didn't change" && line 3 == "Files size didn't change" then print success if it matches.`

Which command can do that ?

Thanks

Comment: IMHO it would be better to modify your script to provide a simple testable [exit status](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html)

Comment: Are you testing the code paths of the script against expected output? Is the expected output exactly what you listed in “something like “?

Comment: Yes it's expected output. I can't modify my script because this is part of an assignment and the output needs to be exactly what they told us. so I thought on testing the assignment with a lot of test cases instead of doing it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `head` and `tail` to get the corresponding lines and values.

Example:

```
OUTPUT=`yourcommand` ; if [ "`echo \"$OUTPUT\" | head -n 1`" = "1 sub-folders added" ] && [ "`echo \"$OUTPUT\" | head -n 2 | tail -n 1`" = "Number of files didn't change" ] && [ "`echo \"$OUTPUT\" | tail -n 1`" = "Files size didn't change" ]  ;then echo "success" ; else echo "error" ; fi
```

(not sure about the `didn't` keywords; you may need to escape the apostrophe with a backslash. (e.g. `\'`).

Looks like you wanted it all in a one-liner, so there it is.

Just be aware that your first line had a space before the number '1'; you may wish to modify either your output or this script.